# New and Updated App(s)

Tags: grammatical-number

#### Should apps be plural in the following circumstances?

"1 New and 1 Updated App(s)"

"150 New and 1 Updated App(s)"

#### Or would it be correct to write...

"1 New App and 1 Updated App"

"150 New Apps and 1 Updated App"

Comment: The second is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing this in a report or letter it would be clear and idiomatic to say "150 new apps and 1 updated one", ”1 new app and 37 updated ones", "150 new apps and no updated ones" and so on. However if you are trying to design a message to come up automatically that would probably require quite a few more lines of code than your original examples.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you look at it, so both are correct.

You could say the first one is correct because it can be split into two sections:

> 150 New, and 1 Updated, Apps

In this instance, "apps" is the object of both "new" and "updated", and because there is more than one new app, the object "app(s)" must become plural.